# How to send a float/double array to R as a vector from JAVA through RServe

Tags: java, r, postgresql, rserve

I'm using **R** with **Java** through **Rserve**,
I want to use **forecasting** w.r.t **ARIMA** in R but the values/data which use to forecast is present in **postgres** DB.
I'm also aware that I can use **RPostgreSQL** directly in R to get data from DB, but before sending to the R I want to process DB data in JAVA later on I want to transfer to R,So for this I'm able to get data from **postgres DB** and right away I'll process to primitive float/double array type and I'm trying to send to R through **'Rserve'** and it is throwing **syntax error** exception. I'm totally new to this R and I'm finding difficulty in making this. 
Please anybody review the problem and comment your suggestions.

For better understanding please view the below snippet:

```
List<Float> xfval = new ArrayList<Float>();
Statement data_statement = dbComp.createStatement();
String command = "SELECT * FROM to_forecast";
ResultSet res=data_statement.executeQuery(command);
while(res.next())
{
   xfval.add(res.getFloat("values"));
}
/*
 *
 Here I have process data of 'xfval'
 w.r.t to condition but I'm not disclosing any
 logic w.r.t to processing
 * 
 *
 */ 

RConnection connection = new RConnection();
String load_pkgs = "require(Rserve); require(forecast)";
connection.eval(load_pkgs);
float[] floatArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(xfval.toArray(new Float[0]), 0.0F);

 //below line is that where I'm getting the syntax error exception
connection.eval("xData=("+floatArray+")").asDouble();
String strx2 = "x = xData[1:100,1];";
connection.eval(strx2);
/*the code continues*/
```

And I also want to have suggestion using **ARIMA** and **forecasting** techniques directly in **JAVA** without using **R**.
The thing I opted for R is that R can perform ARIMA and forecasting techniques.Please if there is any Open Source API's or libraries for JAVA  let me asap.

For Exception details I'm attaching below image:

[image: Exception for Syntax Err]

Thank You

Comment: I doubt `"xData=("+floatArray+"` will give you what you want. have you tried `"xData=("+Arrays.toString(floatArray)+"`. Also you might want to add the syntax error you are getting.

Comment: @BevynQ I tried your suggestion there is no effect... :( if you know any technique for forecasting in Java without using R please let me know

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the RConnection documentation, eval function takes a String as its argument. So you need to create a String that is properly formatted for R.

This may work:

```
    String rVectorStr="";
    for(int i=0;i<floatArray.length;i++) {
        if(i==floatArray.length-1)
            rVectorStr=rVectorStr.concat(String.valueOf(floatArray[i]));
        else
            rVectorStr=rVectorStr.concat(String.valueOf(floatArray[i])+",");
    }
    //System.out.println(rVectorStr);
    connection.eval("xData=c("+rVectorStr+")");
    String strx2 = "x = xData[1:100,1];";
```

The as.Double() is used to receive outputs (generated by R after evaluating the string sent inside eval()), and store them as Java Double type. It isn't something that sends Double arrays to R. There is no such method in Rserve.

Comment: Happy to give further explanation if needed

Comment: Hi actually I'm using the ARIMA Model for forecasting some xdata like substation usage load to predict future load if u know how to do in completely in JAVA can u direct me please

Comment: There is nothing in particular specifically focusing on forecasting in Java, but you could take a look at the Apache Commons Math library of you decide to implement the forecasting algorithms by yourself. Otherwise R is the preferred way, although deficiencies come time and again in the R forecasting packages depending upon use case. Anyway, did the code above help?

Comment: thanks and i used all R commands to process the data so I did all in eval() method only and thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: hi may be I want to ask you about the forecasting implementation in R please for now can you tell that how many sets of external regressors can I apply to get the ARIMA model result please answer asap.....

Comment: Sorry, I have very less idea about ARIMA.